# Is it possible to uninstall Ola Hallengren SQL maintenance script

Tags: sql-server

After successful deployment and execution of Ola Hallengren SQL maintenance script, I found [this](http://sqlgokely.blogspot.rs/2012/10/uninstall-ola-hallengren-maintenance.html) but it is not working. So is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Why are you uninstalling it? It's not meant to be a "one use" tool - you install it and schedule the jobs to run regularly to keep your databases healthy.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I was using it for testing only. @alroc

Comment: Manually drop the objects created by the maintenance script?

Comment: Yes, that is a option, but I was thinking someone had a same situation like I did. @JodyT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DatabaseBackup]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DatabaseBackup]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[IndexOptimize]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[IndexOptimize]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[CommandExecute]') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[CommandExecute]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DatabaseSelect]') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[DatabaseSelect]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[CommandLog]') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[CommandLog]

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'CommandLog Cleanup') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'CommandLog Cleanup'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - DIFF') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - DIFF'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - LOG') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - LOG'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - SYSTEM_DATABASES') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - SYSTEM_DATABASES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'Output File Cleanup') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'Output File Cleanup'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'sp_delete_backuphistory') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'sp_delete_backuphistory'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE [name] = 'sp_purge_jobhistory') EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'sp_purge_jobhistory'
```

Comment: /*----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====
JOBS
----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====*/
SELECT *
FROM msdb..sysjobs
WHERE description LIKE '%HALLENGREN%'
GO

/*----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====
STORED PROCS
----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====----====*/
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
 ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%hallengren%'
 AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'